# How can install sbt on my mac brew and port not working on terminal?

Tags: macos

how can i install sbt on my mac ???

..my java version is "1.8.0_05" 
and I used with port and brew terminal showing me  command not found 
like :

"ekram$ port install sbt 
-bash: port: command not found

ekram$port install sbt 
-bash: port: command not found"

Comment: Have you installed MacPorts or Homebrew? It sounds like you haven't. Try the installation instructions at https://brew.sh/ or https://www.macports.org/install.php

Comment: No how can install macPorts ? !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download, say, `sbt-0.13.15.tgz` from [scala-sbt site](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html), expand it under somewhere like /Users/leo/local/sbt/, then include its binary subdirectory in your PATH:

```
export PATH=/Users/leo/local/sbt/bin:$PATH
```